# Move run loops from python to graph with tf.while_loop in tensorflow

Tags: python, optimization, while-loop, tensorflow

The code is here(sorry for the first line is not indent)
Look at the optimizer in __init__

```
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
```

This is ok.But if I replace it with other optimizers as

```
optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.002,0.9)
```

Then the summaries dequeue'd from the FIFOQueue are all the same.
It seems that the loss calculated in the function "body" would not be updated.
I supposed to write a simpler example here,but that example did not have the problem.
It probably depends on my calculate graph . So,I paste the main code here.
I don't know what's wrong,please help!
Sorry for pool English.

```
class BonePosition:
def __del__(self):
    self.sess.close()

def calclocation(self):#->[vertexNum,matx]
    pose = tf.gather(self.pose, self.index,name="gather_pose")  # [boneNum,matx,maty],[vertexNum,vbnum]->[vertexNum,vbnum,matx,maty]
    bone = tf.gather(self.boneVar, self.index,name="gather_bone") # [boneNum,matx,maty],[vertexNum,vbnum]->[vertexNum,vbnum,matx,maty]
    cat=tf.constant(1.0,dtype=tf.float32,shape=[self.vertexNum,1])
    vertex=tf.concat([self.vertex,cat],axis=1,name="concat_vertex") #[vertexNum,matx+1],makesure maty=matx+1

    vertex=tf.reshape(vertex,[self.vertexNum,self.maty,1])
    pose=tf.reshape(pose,[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum*self.matx,self.maty])
    location=tf.matmul(pose,vertex,name="matmul_pose") #[vertexNum,vbnum*matx,1]
    location=tf.reshape(location,[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum,self.matx])

    cat=tf.reshape(cat,[self.vertexNum,1,1])
    cat=tf.tile(cat,[1,self.vbnum,1],name="tile_cat") #[vertexNum,vbnum,1]
    location=tf.concat([location,cat],axis=2,name="concat_location") #[vertexNum,vbnum,matx+1]
    location=tf.reshape(location,[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum,self.maty,1])
    location=tf.matmul(bone,location,name="matmul_bone") #[vertexNum,vbnum,matx,1]
    location=tf.reshape(location,[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum,self.matx])

    weight=tf.reshape(self.weight,[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum,1])
    location=tf.multiply(location,weight,name="multiply_weight") #[vertexNum,vbnum,matx]
    location=tf.reduce_sum(location,axis=1,name="sum_weight")#[vertexNum,matx]
    return location

def calcloss(self,location): #[vertexNum,matx],[featureNum,matx]->[]
    ab=tf.matmul(location,tf.transpose(self.feature),name="matmul_loss") #[vertexNum,featureNum]
    a=tf.reduce_sum(location*location,axis=1,name="sum_location") #[vertexNum]
    b=tf.reduce_sum(self.feature*self.feature,axis=1,name="sum_feature") #[featureNum]
    a=tf.reshape(a,[self.vertexNum,1])
    b=tf.reshape(b,[1,self.featureNum])
    loss=a-2*ab+b #[vertexNum,featureNum],Distance(A,B)=(A-B)(A-B)=AA-2AB+BB
    loss=tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_min(loss,axis=0,name="min_distance"),name="sum_loss")
    return loss

def body(self,i,queue,optimizer,logdir):
    loss=self.calcloss(self.calclocation())
    opt=optimizer.minimize(loss)
    if logdir is not None:
        summary_loss=tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
        queue=queue.enqueue(summary_loss)
        return tf.tuple([i + 1], control_inputs=[opt,queue])
    else:
        return tf.tuple([i + 1], control_inputs=[opt])

def __init__(self,featureNum,boneNum,vertexNum,logdir=None,profile=None):
    self.matx=3
    self.maty=self.matx+1
    self.vbnum=4 #one vertex connects vbnum bones
    self.featureNum=featureNum
    self.boneNum=boneNum
    self.vertexNum=vertexNum
    self.feature=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[self.featureNum,self.matx])
    self.bone=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[self.boneNum,self.matx,self.maty])
    self.boneVar=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,dtype=tf.float32,shape=[self.boneNum,self.matx,self.maty]))
    self.boneInit=tf.assign(self.boneVar,self.bone)
    self.pose=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[self.boneNum,self.matx,self.maty])
    self.vertex=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[self.vertexNum,self.matx])
    self.weight=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum])
    self.index=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[self.vertexNum,self.vbnum])

    self.trainNum=20
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
    #optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.002,0.9) # if use this the loss would not be updated!But why?
    if logdir is not None:
        queue=tf.FIFOQueue(self.trainNum,dtypes=tf.string)
        self.summary=queue.dequeue()
    self.y=tf.while_loop(lambda i:i<self.trainNum,lambda i:self.body(i,queue,optimizer,logdir),[tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.int32)])

    self.sess=tf.Session()
    self.logdir=logdir
    if self.logdir is not None:
        subdir = self.sublogdir(self.logdir)
        self.writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(subdir, self.sess.graph)
    self.profile=profile

def train(self,feed_dict):
    options=None
    metadata=None
    if self.profile is not None:
        options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
        metadata=tf.RunMetadata()
    self.sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),self.boneInit],feed_dict={self.bone:feed_dict[self.bone]},options=options,run_metadata=metadata)
    self.sess.run(self.y,feed_dict=feed_dict,options=options,run_metadata=metadata)
    self.writeprofile(metadata)
    if self.logdir is not None:
        for i in range(0,self.trainNum):
            summary=self.sess.run(self.summary,options=options,run_metadata=metadata)
            #print(summary)
            self.writer.add_summary(summary,i)
    bone=self.sess.run(self.boneVar,options=options,run_metadata=metadata)
    return bone

def sublogdir(self,logdir):
    now = datetime.now()
    subdir = logdir + "/ev_" + now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    return subdir

def writeprofile(self,metadata):
    if self.profile is None:
        return
    tl=timeline.Timeline(metadata.step_stats)
    #ctf=tl.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_dataflow=True,show_memory=True)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open(self.profile+".json","w") as f:
        f.write(ctf)
```

Comment: That's hard to say, but it might be that your learning rate is small enough that your steps are not doing anything. Try changing the optimizer parameters

Comment: I tried several learning rates,but the loss dequeued from the FIFOQueue are all the same. The loss can not be accessed outside the loop，so I can not see it directly,I see it by dequeuing from the FIFOQueue。But If I calculate another loss outside the loop，I can see the loss has been trained。So I think maybe the problem is from the FIFOQueue？

Comment: I think enqueuing summaries is a rare enough thing that there could be a bug. Why not use the standard monitored session way of saving summaries?

Comment: But how to do that?  I tried to use MonitoredSession with SummarySaverHook,but got "RuntimeError: Global step should be created to use SummarySaverHook" .Even if it works,I don't know if it fit my surcumstance. I want to get multiple summaries in one run.

Comment: Create a global step using tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step and update it in your model update op.

Comment: Now I return back to use the classical for loop in python,Leaving the problem unsolved.Anyway,thank you very much @AlexandrePassos